# JSON parse error.

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson

I am trying to convert an json string returned from a web service to local class object on android.

but got error: `java.lang.String` cannot be converted to `JSONArray`

the string returned is:

```
[{"Id":592,"RadioName":"CRI怀旧金曲(128Kbps)","RadioAddress":"mmst","Priority":0,"GroupId":14,"GroupDesc":"热门","RadioCountry":"China(中国)","Valid":1,"Vip":0,"LanguageDesc":"China(中国)"},{"Id":594,"RadioName":"猫扑网络电台(32Kbps)","RadioAddress":"mmst","Priority":1,"GroupId":14,"GroupDesc":"热门","RadioCountry":"China(中国)","Valid":1,"Vip":0,"LanguageDesc":"China(中国)"}]
```

the code I am using is:

```
            String result= convertStreamToString(instream);
            try {
                JSONArray responseObject = new JSONArray(result);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

if I manually assign above returned string to a String variable, the convert is successful, no idea how is that.  please help.

Comment: why do you mention gson if you use JSONArray?

Comment: Could you post your Gson code? And the POJO used by the Gson?

Comment: Also if I ma not wrong you say that the `result` string is constructed incorrectly. If you want us to check that post the code of the `convertStreamToString`

Comment: Thanks for all your help.

i have found the cause.
the returned string is in the format of "[]" instead of [].
the quote is the killer.
another strange cause is that the returned quote " is translated into \" which becomes two characters in the java string.  anyway, i manually removed the '\', it starts working.